# Identifying the Source of Multiple Azure SQL Query Calls Causing High CPU Consumption

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL query that is being called multiple times, and it's causing high CPU consumption. I suspect that the query is being called from multiple pages or locations within my application, but I'm having trouble pinpointing the source.

Is there a way to track and identify from which page or location within my application this query is being called? I want to optimize its usage and potentially reduce the CPU consumption it's causing.

Any suggestions or tools that can help me trace the origin of these repeated query calls would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
SELECT
clmns.name AS [Name],
clmns.column_id AS [ID],
clmns.is_nullable AS [Nullable],
clmns.is_computed AS [Computed],
CAST(ISNULL(cik.index_column_id, 0) AS bit) AS [InPrimaryKey],
clmns.is_ansi_padded AS [AnsiPaddingStatus],
CAST(clmns.is_rowguidcol AS bit) AS [RowGuidCol],
CAST(ISNULL(cc.is_persisted, 0) AS bit) AS [IsPersisted],
ISNULL(clmns.collation_name, N'') AS [Collation],
CAST(ISNULL((select TOP 1 1 from sys.foreign_key_columns AS colfk where colfk.parent_column_id = clmns.column_id and colfk.parent_object_id = clmns.object_id), 0) AS bit) AS [IsForeignKey],
clmns.is_identity AS [Identity],
CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value,0) AS bigint) AS [IdentitySeed],
CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value,0) AS bigint) AS [IdentityIncrement],
(case when clmns.default_object_id = 0 then N'' when d.parent_object_id > 0 then N'' else d.name end) AS [Default],
(case when clmns.default_object_id = 0 then N'' when d.parent_object_id > 0 then N'' else schema_name(d.schema_id) end) AS [DefaultSchema],
ISNULL(dc.Name, N'') AS [DefaultConstraintName],
(case when clmns.rule_object_id = 0 then N'' else r.name end) AS [Rule],
(case when clmns.rule_object_id = 0 then N'' else schema_name(r.schema_id) end) AS [RuleSchema],
CAST(ISNULL(COLUMNPROPERTY(clmns.object_id, clmns.name, N'IsDeterministic'),0) AS bit) AS [IsDeterministic],
CAST(ISNULL(COLUMNPROPERTY(clmns.object_id, clmns.name, N'IsPrecise'),0) AS bit) AS [IsPrecise],
ISNULL(ic.is_not_for_replication, 0) AS [NotForReplication],
CAST(COLUMNPROPERTY(clmns.object_id, clmns.name, N'IsFulltextIndexed') AS bit) AS [IsFullTextIndexed],
CAST(clmns.encryption_type AS int) AS [EncryptionType],
clmns.encryption_algorithm_name AS [EncryptionAlgorithm],
clmns.column_encryption_key_id AS [ColumnEncryptionKeyID],
ceks.name AS [ColumnEncryptionKeyName],
CAST(clmns.is_filestream AS bit) AS [IsFileStream],
CAST(clmns.is_sparse AS bit) AS [IsSparse],
CAST(clmns.is_column_set AS bit) AS [IsColumnSet],
usrt.name AS [DataType],
s1clmns.name AS [DataTypeSchema],
ISNULL(baset.name, N'') AS [SystemType],
CAST(CASE WHEN baset.name IN (N'nchar', N'nvarchar') AND clmns.max_length <> -1 THEN clmns.max_length/2 ELSE clmns.max_length END AS int) AS [Length],
CAST(clmns.precision AS int) AS [NumericPrecision],
CAST(clmns.scale AS int) AS [NumericScale],
ISNULL(xscclmns.name, N'') AS [XmlSchemaNamespace],
ISNULL(s2clmns.name, N'') AS [XmlSchemaNamespaceSchema],
ISNULL( (case clmns.is_xml_document when 1 then 2 else 1 end), 0) AS [XmlDocumentConstraint],
CASE WHEN usrt.is_table_type = 1 THEN N'structured' ELSE N'' END AS [UserType],
clmns.generated_always_type AS [GeneratedAlwaysType],
CAST(clmns.is_hidden AS bit) AS [IsHidden],
CAST(clmns.is_masked AS bit) AS [IsMasked],
ISNULL(clmns.graph_type, 0) AS [GraphType]
FROM
sys.tables AS tbl
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS clmns ON clmns.object_id=tbl.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes AS ik ON ik.object_id = clmns.object_id and 1=ik.is_primary_key
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.index_columns AS cik ON cik.index_id = ik.index_id and cik.column_id = clmns.column_id and cik.object_id = clmns.object_id and 0 = cik.is_included_column
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.computed_columns AS cc ON cc.object_id = clmns.object_id and cc.column_id = clmns.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.identity_columns AS ic ON ic.object_id = clmns.object_id and ic.column_id = clmns.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects AS d ON d.object_id = clmns.default_object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.default_constraints as dc ON clmns.default_object_id = dc.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects AS r ON r.object_id = clmns.rule_object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.column_encryption_keys AS ceks ON (ceks.column_encryption_key_id = clmns.column_encryption_key_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types AS usrt ON usrt.user_type_id = clmns.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas AS s1clmns ON s1clmns.schema_id = usrt.schema_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types AS baset ON (baset.user_type_id = clmns.system_type_id and baset.user_type_id = baset.system_type_id) or ((baset.system_type_id = clmns.system_type_id) and (baset.user_type_id = clmns.user_type_id) and (baset.is_user_defined = 0) and (baset.is_assembly_type = 1)) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.xml_schema_collections AS xscclmns ON xscclmns.xml_collection_id = clmns.xml_collection_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas AS s2clmns ON s2clmns.schema_id = xscclmns.schema_id
WHERE
(clmns.name=@_msparam_0)and((tbl.name=@_msparam_1 and SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)=@_msparam_2))
OPTION (FORCE ORDER)
```

Need to find way to track and identify from which page or location within my application this query is being called? I want to optimize its usage and potentially reduce the CPU consumption it's causing.

Comment: No, SQL Server has no way to know what part of your app made the call unless you explicitly find a way to pass it in, for example as a parameter in a stored procedure.

Comment: You could implement different connection strings using the application name property to track the query origin.

Comment: you can hook your application with Azure Application Insights and see the source, I will also recommend to create an index of your table so that the query execution gets faster

Comment: This looks like a query sent by SSMS. Do you have a lot of objects in the database?

Comment: there's usually a program name attached to most connections and queries, but that's about it. As Martin wrote, this looks like a query that fetches table metadata, and unless your application deals with sql server management, i doubt it's coming from those. Probably the real problem is somewhere else

Comment: Is your application an Entity Framework application?

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, we have around 30k tables

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo yes we are using entity framework

Comment: @CoreIP On my answer I am providing the best approach I know. Developers were facing the same issue on my organization, and they were happy to use that approach. Hope it fits your needs.

Comment: You probably want to encourage people to disable intellisense when they connect to it in SSMS if the CPU usage caused by this query is enough to cause an actual problem

Answer (score 0):

You can start using [Query Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tags) in your code. These tags are visible on the Query Store reports available on SQL Server Management Studio and on Azure Portal ([Query Performance Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/query-performance-insight-use?view=azuresql)) and will appear on queries captured by [Extended Events](https://www.bing.com/search?pglt=41&q=sql%20azure%20extended%20events&cvid=db0052ec70a142dfbbf0ebb8f9c87ea4&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBAgAEAAyBAgAEAAyBAgBEAAyBAgCEAAyBAgDEAAyBggEEEUYPNIBCDcyNzlqMGoxqAIAsAIA&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=WSEDDB) also.

```
var myLocation = new Point(1, 2);
var nearestPeople = (from f in context.People.TagWith("This is my spatial query!")
                     orderby f.Location.Distance(myLocation) descending
                     select f).Take(5).ToList();
```

A similar but maybe better option worthy to try is [EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.TagWithCallSite Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.tagwithcallsite?view=efcore-7.0) that creates a tag with source file name and line where method was called. Examples can be found [here](https://thirty25.com/posts/2021/12/tagging-query-with-ef-core).

```
public static IQueryable<T> TagWithSource<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable,
    string tag = default,
    [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0,
    [CallerFilePath] string filePath = "",
    [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
    [CallerArgumentExpression("queryable")]
    string argument = "")
{
    // argument could be multiple lines with whitespace so let's normalize it down to one line
    var trimmedLines = string.Join(
        string.Empty,
        argument.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(i => i.Trim())
    );

    var tagContent = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag)
        ? default
        : tag + Environment.NewLine;

    tagContent += trimmedLines + Environment.NewLine + $" at {memberName}  - {filePath}:{lineNumber}";

    return queryable.TagWith(tagContent);
}
```